Variable size sliding window- Subarray Sum Equals K
I tried solving variable size sliding windows problem but my test case if failing for
nums =[-1,-1,1], k =0 , Output=0, Expected =1
https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/description/
here is my solving for above problem, I know many different solving are available but I want to solve by my approach. Can some one please improve my logic below. Thanks
private static int subarraySum(int[] nums, int k) {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

            while (j < nums.length) {
                // condition
                sum = sum + nums[j];

                if (sum < k) {
                    j++;
                } else if (sum == k) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    sum = sum - nums[i];
                    i++;
                    j++;
                } else if (sum > k) {
                    while (sum > k) {
                        sum = sum - nums[i];
                        if (sum > 0 && sum == k) {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    j++;
                }

            }
        
        return count;
    }

Test case is failing
